# Fixed Header Height

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I made an Wordpress Mobile Theme, on the single page i made the HEADER fixed, on iPhone if the view mode is landscape the header height is 50%, in css i write for the header { height:70px; } but just on the iPhone (landscape) the header height is 50%. Thx.

header css:

```
#header { width:100%; float:left; height:70px; }
.fixed { position:fixed; top:0; }
```

Comment: Is there some sort of @media screen and (max-width: 767px){} in the CSS that tells the header to be 50% height? Additionally you could put an `!important` after the height. But it could also be your nav elements pushing down to multiple lines... hard to tell without more info.

Comment: does it look like 50% to you or have you somewhere proven that it is 50%? In landscape mode the iphone screen has a viewport height of 219px. For sure a 70px header is then very big (1/3 of the screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your stylesheet. It will only trigger if the window is

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    #header { height:50%; }
}
```

You will also need to add this to the head tag of your page the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your question, but if you don't want the header to be 50%, just enter the appropriate size there. This size will only affect small devices in landscape mode.